# What are the braces in this makefile rule for?

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

I am reading a makefile for a Qt-created project that has the following:

```
{backend}.cpp{release\}.obj::
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -Forelease\ @<<
    $<  
<<
```

*(above code is using \t for recipe and is as written in makefile)*

Both the rule and the recipe confuse me.

I'll start with `{backend}` in the rule. Obviously the same confusion for `{release}` as well. I assume this is a reference to a particular sub-directory named `backend`. I guess that `..\backend\release\bar.obj` would be found as a legitimate target? But what part of **make** says this is legitimate syntax and what exactly happens here?

FWIW: This is in a section commented as: `##### implicit rules`.
Version: `GNU Make 4.2.1 Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin`

Bonus points:

Explain the use of `@<<` and `<<` in the recipe... (*Yes, I'm lacking in bash shell finesse...*). Is this referencing the first prerequisite with `$<` and silently redirecting it? Why isn't it `$$<`?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a link to that file in their GitHub repo?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the comment, I edited the question to make it clearer - this makefile is from a locally Qt-created project, not one that is a Qt github project.

Comment: These curly-braces have no meaning to GNU make, so as far as it's concerned they are just treated like any other character.  Additionally, the `@<<` stuff is not legal GNU make (unless possibly they've set `.ONESHELL` somewhere in the makefile).  I suspect that the generated makefile here is wrong.

Comment: Also, can you check the content of your example above and fix the formatting of the last line?  Is it supposed to be just `<<` or something else?

Comment: Figured out how to get the code formatting correct. The << is at the beginning of it's own line right after the line above it.  Not finding .ONESHELL anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is an NMAKE batch-mode rule

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/batch-mode-rules?view=vs-2017

The equivalent GNU Make rule would be something like

```
backend/%.obj: release/%.cpp:
```

With the difference that, as the name suggests, these rules will invoke their recipes only once for all valid targets and expect the rule to create all of the targets in a single pass with the `$<` macro.

The `<<` syntax is NMAKE's inline file feature

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/inline-files-in-a-makefile?view=vs-2017

This expands and captures everything between the angle brackets and saves it to a file, in this case a temporary file as no filename is specified after the brackets. The file is then passed to the compiler as a response file on the first line of the recipe through the [`@`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/at-specify-a-compiler-response-file?view=vs-2017) option.

Comment: That's brilliant! Thank you, I totally forgot about NMAKE!